# How to send message to a SOAP based webservice without sending any SOAP headers

Tags: soap, biztalk

I have a SOAP based Web service that I need to send a message to.
I am using a WCF basic-http adapter.

I want to send an empty SOAP Header in my message but it sending some Security details which the server does not understand.
Is there a way to exclude the SOAPHeader from my Outbound message.

Also, I am using https protocol, so cannot use "NONE" as  mode of authentication.

Comment: Can you give some details about which security details it does not understand?  That way someone might be able to suggest how to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Then it sounds like the service is not fully SOAP compliant.

If you switch to the WCF-WebHttp Adapter, you can craft the SOAP message entirely on your own.  Meaning, don't rely on WCF to do that for you.

That way, you can produce whatever output the service expects.